# Why are there more comments on the formatting of my post rather than help and direction with my problem?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How do I create a batch file to process XML files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461522/how-do-i-create-a-batch-file-to-process-xml-files-in-a-directory)

Why are there more comments on the formatting of my post rather than help and direction with my problem?  I actually followed a question similar to the one I was asking.    One of the comments said it was closed, which is why I asked the question a second time.

I got a comment:

> This question is not a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and will be closed.

One commenter is telling me "minimal" and another is telling the post needs more information.

First I see a post that my post is being closed.  I create a second post and then I'm told the to delete the 2nd post.

I'm a little confused, are you here to help with a problem or here to correct posts?  Do the same people that are here to answer questions look for incorrect posts?

Comment: To help with the problem, people need to understand it. To gain understanding, it has to be in a medium that allows it. You can't help someone speaking a language you don't know about, but you can tell them how others could be able to understand.

Comment: _"are you here to help with a problem or here to correct post?"_ Many people are here to help building a FAQ like repository with good and clear questions, which are helpful for future research, rather to help individuals solving their niche problems or typographical errors.

Comment: _"Do the same people that are here to answer questions look for incorrect posts?"_ Indeed, they do, because they _want_ to answer you, but they can't if the information they need isn't there.

Comment: Also, stack overflow's purpose is to develop an excellent set of questions and answers for future reference. Think of it as more like a wiki than a discussion group. So editing is very common, and questions that don't add value to the site may be ignored or removed.

Comment: *Do the same people that are here to answer questions look for incorrect posts?* Yes, of course we do.

Comment: If a question is closed, it **means it was not asked right**. In this case, you should **edit the *same* question** and **fix the problem** so it can be reopened. If you are unsure why it was closed, you should *read what the comments tell you to do* and then **do that**. If you are still confused after that, you can check out the [help] and see [ask]. **DO NOT REPOST THE QUESTION.** This will end with the same thing happening again. (Oh, and sorry abou the amount of **bold**. I hope this doesn't come across as me yelling, because I am not `:)`)

Comment: `are you here to help with a problem or here to correct post?` This is actually a interesting question, and it is one of the main points a lot new users get confused about SO. **Answer: We are here to correct post, so that your post can help not only you, but other programmers experiencing similar problem like you. If the only one can get helped by your post is you yourself, then it doesn't deserve to stay on stackoverflow.**

Comment: *One commenter is telling me "minimal" and another is telling the post needs more information.* They were actually saying the same thing, which was that your post didn't have at least the minimum amount of information necessary to answer it. More specifically, it didn't have the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 16):

Right, so...

- The question doesn't appear to be asking anything concrete.  It lists a starting point and it lists a file, but it doesn't include what kind of file you're trying to parse (XML files are different, they just *are*), and more importantly, **you don't include any sample of what the file is.**  Although that may be less pronounced by the fact that...
- ...**you don't actually *ask* a question**.   As I said before, you're just stating what's going on.  You don't give any indication as to what's broken, what's missing, what you're seeing...so we're just as in the dark about this as you are.

I think at this point the comments have run their course and would warrant a clean-up, but you *must* include more information in the question itself about what's going on, and what you're actually *asking* about.

Remember:  this isn't a forum.  We expect questions to have questions.  Comments aren't meant for extended questions.

Comment: I am not  parsing any files.  we don't open them.  We don't care what content of the file is.  it could absolutely be an empty file.  the executable will assign an error code to it that is all we need to know besides the file name.  so how should have i asked the question.. how do i modify my existing batch file to do multiple files?  I don't know how else I can explain it.  It is a shame that I get more comments than possible solutions.

Comment: So then @Sally, effectively your question is, "In a batch file running an external executable, how do I get the name of the file the executable is running, and how do I get its error code?"  It sounds like those are two distinct problems which may lead to someone closing the question as a duplicate (which isn't bad - you could get your answer that way!), but that's one of the details your question is lacking today.

Comment: @Sally It helps to assume good faith with this stuff - you don't know how else to explain it, nothing wrong with that, but it's obviously not getting across to the people who are reading it at the moment, and they're trying to clarify/help where they can in the comments. If you lurk on SO for a bit you'll see that people are pretty much _desperate_ to answer questions (they usually get fancy unicorn points for it after all), it's worth considering that their intentions are mostly honourable

Comment: @Sally the people that **want** to help you are asking you to be clearer in your need. I can be super willing to help you, but if you speak in Russian... For the life of me I won't be able to. That's what you're seeing here: people willing to help, but asking you to clarify what help you need first.

Comment: @Sally when you ask a question, think that people who are going to read it know the language but have absolutly no idea what you are trying to do, even if it seems obvious to you.